# pass all column names to pmap() inside mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tibble, tidyeval

When doing a `pmap` inside `mutate`, I often like to use the following construction so that I can reference the plain column names inside the `map` function instead of `..1`, `..2`, etc. and having to keep track of the order I gave them in:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  nest(data = -c(vs, am, gear, carb)) %>%
  mutate(plot = pmap(lst(vs, am, gear, carb, data), ~with(list(...), {
    
    # not relevant to question, just example task:
    ggplot(data = data, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
      labs(subtitle = (paste0("am=", am, "\n",
                             "carb=", carb, "\n",
                             "gear=", gear, "\n",
                             "vs=", vs)))
  })))
#> # A tibble: 14 x 6
#>       vs    am  gear  carb data             plot  
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>           <list>
#>  1     0     1     4     4 <tibble [2 x 7]> <gg>  
#>  2     1     1     4     1 <tibble [4 x 7]> <gg>  
#>  3     1     0     3     1 <tibble [3 x 7]> <gg>  
#>  4     0     0     3     2 <tibble [4 x 7]> <gg>  
#>  5     0     0     3     4 <tibble [5 x 7]> <gg>  
#>  6     1     0     4     2 <tibble [2 x 7]> <gg>  
#>  7     1     0     4     4 <tibble [2 x 7]> <gg>  
#>  8     0     0     3     3 <tibble [3 x 7]> <gg>  
#>  9     1     1     4     2 <tibble [2 x 7]> <gg>  
#> 10     0     1     5     2 <tibble [1 x 7]> <gg>  
#> 11     1     1     5     2 <tibble [1 x 7]> <gg>  
#> 12     0     1     5     4 <tibble [1 x 7]> <gg>  
#> 13     0     1     5     6 <tibble [1 x 7]> <gg>  
#> 14     0     1     5     8 <tibble [1 x 7]> <gg>
```

My question is, what can I put inside `lst()` in order to pass all columns to the mapped function instead of writing all of them out like I have above? I tried `names(.)` and `!!!names(.)` as my first attempts. Alternatively, if there's a more parsimonious way to do this, like without using `lst()`, that would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass everything you could just use `.` without specifying each column individually.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  nest(data = -c(vs, am, gear, carb)) %>%
  mutate(plot = pmap(., ~with(list(...), {
    # not relevant to question, just example task:
    ggplot(data = data, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
      labs(subtitle = (paste0("am=", am, "\n",
                              "carb=", carb, "\n",
                              "gear=", gear, "\n",
                              "vs=", vs)))
  })))

#      vs    am  gear  carb data             plot  
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>           <list>
# 1     0     1     4     4 <tibble [2 × 7]> <gg>  
# 2     1     1     4     1 <tibble [4 × 7]> <gg>  
# 3     1     0     3     1 <tibble [3 × 7]> <gg>  
# 4     0     0     3     2 <tibble [4 × 7]> <gg>  
# 5     0     0     3     4 <tibble [5 × 7]> <gg>  
# 6     1     0     4     2 <tibble [2 × 7]> <gg>  
# 7     1     0     4     4 <tibble [2 × 7]> <gg>  
# 8     0     0     3     3 <tibble [3 × 7]> <gg>  
# 9     1     1     4     2 <tibble [2 × 7]> <gg>  
#10     0     1     5     2 <tibble [1 × 7]> <gg>  
#11     1     1     5     2 <tibble [1 × 7]> <gg>  
#12     0     1     5     4 <tibble [1 × 7]> <gg>  
#13     0     1     5     6 <tibble [1 × 7]> <gg>  
#14     0     1     5     8 <tibble [1 × 7]> <gg>
```

Comment: Note that this will not work properly with grouped data frames: `pmap()` will be evaluated one time per group but will receive the whole data frame (via the magrittr `.` placeholder) rather than just a group slice.

Comment: In which case using `cur_data()` would be preferred?

Comment: oh yeah I think so